# How show an uploaded image saved outside ear in a jsp using stuts2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

In my project users upload image files which are saved outside the context root in the drives. I need to show these images in a jsp. I use struts2. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-dynamic-image-example/). I think that is exactly what you are looking for.

**Edit**:

The idea is to tell the action what image you want. That is done adding a parameter in the request. In the example, for instance, it is use the parameter `imageId` but you can change this strategy and use a different thing, like the image name. Then you should call the action in this way (according to the tutorial):

```
http://localhost:8080/myAppContext/ImageAction?imageId=darksouls.jpg
```

Also, take in mind the @Dave Newton's comment as a very good alternative. See this other [example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-download-file-example/) for that.

Comment: Maybe, but using a "stream" result type already works without having to do anything in particular, and makes for a very short action when using Commons IO to copy the image stream.

Comment: Ok what if I have multiple images to be displayed, how will this work?

Comment: I that got, thanks jddsantaella. One more doubt, what if instead of imageId, I give userId(a unique key to identify an user) and want to get all the images uploaded by that user. Should i use multiple streams. How can it be done?

Comment: You cannot download multiple files in one click. If you want to download all images belonged to some user, you will need to create a zip, for example, with all the images and then download the zip.

Comment: No I dont want to download, I want to display those images on a jsp.

Comment: You cannot do it in one call. You need to call the action one time for each image you want to display. Remember that you will need a html `<img />` for each one. But you can do it programmatically, for example, using a `<c:foreach .. />` over a list of an user images.

Comment: So say if I have 20 images. And I use <c: foreach /> tag isn't like processing 20 image action requests right? Won't performance take a hit?

Comment: Yes, it could hit the performance, not necessarily, but I do not know another way according with your strategy. A better solution would be to store the uploaded images somewhere and make them available via an static server as an Apache. By the way, your original question was answered.