# Writing multiple images to ServletOuputStream?

Tags: java, servlets, java-io

I've a requirement where I get multiple images from web service(ex:List) and have to write those images to ServletOutputStream.

When I click on the 'VIEW' link it invokes servlet and that servlet invokes webservice and receives multiple images as a List.

Now I'm trying to write those images to ServletOutputStream which is not working..

Trying to send the images as zip

```
response.setContentType("application/zip");
  OutputStream os = null;
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
ZipOutputStream zos = null;     
try{
    os = resp.getOutputStream();
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

    zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
    zos.setLevel(ZipOutputStream.STORED);

    sendMultipleFiles(zos, annotContent,"display");
}catch (IOException e) {
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
} finally {
    if (zos != null) {
        zos.finish();
        zos.flush();
    }
    bos.close();
    os.close();
}

private void sendMultipleFiles(ZipOutputStream zos, Collection<byte[]> filesToSend, String name) throws IOException {
    myLogger.info("sendMultipleFiles is invoked..");
    for(byte[] f: filesToSend) {

        InputStream inStream = null;
        ZipEntry ze = null;

        try {
            inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(f);

            ze = new ZipEntry(name + "-archived");
            ze.setComment("Dummy file");

            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            int readByte = 0;
            while((readByte = inStream.read()) != -1)
            {
                zos.write(readByte);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find " );
        } finally {
            if (ze != null) {
                zos.closeEntry();
            }
            inStream.close();

        }
    }
```

Above code is not working..any suggestions would be appreciated..

Comment: You should create a zip file and add each image in there one by one. Then, write the content of the zip file to the OutputStream.

Comment: What's the client in this case? Usually you'd serve HTML which would refer to multiple images, each of which would cause a separate request. Please give us more context.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Using JSF..when I click on the 'VIEW' link it has to invoke servlet and response(images) should be displayed as popup.

Comment: So it's HTML being displayed in a browser? In that case, I suggest you start thinking about what the brower's going to see - which is *one* response for the HTML, which will then trigger a request per image...

Comment: No HTML..when I click on  the link it invokes servlet that the response is automatically being displayed in a new popup.

Comment: @TP_JAVA how is the popup supposed to split the response it gets, extract the images, and display them. A browser can't do that. HTML doesn't support that. And HTML is what your browser popup uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will depend on the content-type you are serving - If you are serving an HTML response the issue can be resolved by either storing the images on the disk ([outside the context root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059479/how-show-an-uploaded-image-saved-outside-ear-in-a-jsp-using-stuts2) and writing a image display endpoint) or if the images are small - sending the bytes out as [base64 encoding in the image tag directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943729/how-to-display-an-image-which-is-in-bytes-to-jsp-page-using-html-tags).

If your response type is not HTML - here are some options - you could return a [ZIP file](http://www.myhowto.org/java/54-sending-multiple-files-in-single-http-response-using-java-servlet/).

Less standard way of using a servlet with [MultiPart MIME Extension](http://www.myhowto.org/java/54-sending-multiple-files-in-single-http-response-using-java-servlet/).

**Edit:**
As per the comment the mime type is JPEG - one option is to combine JPEG into one larger one (cannot send multiple out). Combining the bytes of a binary file - JPEG has it's own format for compression along with header, footer and EXIF info - you may need specialized APIs to combine them into one. [Here](http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-merge-multiple-images-into-one.html) is one that I came across. If combining the JPG is not an option - what you are trying to achieve cannot be done in one write.

Comment: My Mime type is : image/jpeg - not using html                                                    Trying to merge the PDFS and writing to output stream..modified the code..pls refer above

Comment: I don't see what you mention here in the comment, however I have edited the answer - hope it helps.

Comment: what do you mean by not working? Have a stack trace or error to share?

Comment: Resolved it by merging images using the API  and writing to OutputStream.